# Google assistant android integration

Tags: android, android-intent, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I know it's possible to integrate an app with a command like

> Ask 'someApp' about something

or other similar phrases.

Is it possible to ask google assistant simply

> Close the kitchen window.

And then it pass that information to that device directly?
I thinks this is the `direct actions` job, however it's not available to the public yet and it's under development.

So how can I pass this data to my app and process that myself?

Comment: is there any solution ? i am facing same as you.

Answer (score 1):

> Close the Kitchen window

I think that this would only work if google was able to inherently handle this command.  Since Direct Actions has not been developed yet, I am unsure exactly how the input would be formatted, but in either case (direct action or the current methods), fulfillment on actions not native to Assistant are to be handled by you.  For something *like* this, you would need to setup an action on Actions on Google so that whenever this is action is called, it sends a request to your service via a webhook.

Direct actions refer to actions that google figures out what the user wants, and then you would fulfill this action yourself.  Basically, using this would free you from having to write test cases and responses for whatever the user says. As far as I know, you have to give your action set some name, which the user mentions so that they can use your action.  This action then calls on you to complete the action and return some response.  Actions on Google has plenty of documentation for doing this through API.AI and Actions SDK, where the former is probably the easier way of doing this.

[Conversation Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/conversation)

[Starting with API.AI](https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/apiai/tutorials/getting-started)

Disclaimer: I have only read through the documentation for Actions on Google, I have yet to implement any of this, but hopefully this helped clear some things up for you.